# How to make the markdown package work with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: markdown

I want to reuse some markdown snippets in my LaTeX document using the `markdown` package.

I follow the [documentation](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.html#requirements) and create `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
    \begin{markdown}
        Hello *world*!
    \end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Then, I run `lualatex main.tex`:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2023-02-07>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/markdown/markdown.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/markdown/markdown.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/lt3luabridge/lt3luabridge.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paralist/paralist.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csvsimple/csvsimple.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csvsimple/csvsimple-legacy.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gobble/gobble.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gobble/gobble.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
No file main.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(./_markdown_main/0f7a4d6cf80efde3bcdf53b9fbb39890.md.tex) [1{/usr/local/texliv
e/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux))
 504 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 56 glue_spec
, 6 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:31,3:4,4:1,5:23,7:72,9:28
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.
otf></usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono10-regul
ar.otf>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 4620 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
```

And the result I get is just this (the same with `pdflatex --shell-escape`):

[image]

How do I make markdown formatting work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your usage of indent, because an indent of 4 spaces (or more) in markdown is the same like `\begin{verbatim}…\end{verbatim}` in LaTeX or `<pre>…</pre>` in HTML. So just remove the indent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
Hello *world*!
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: And the indent is relative to the file, not to the `markdown` environment.